# Kafka from docker container not showing topics in offset explorer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I am having trouble setting up a kafka / docker to show all topics, this is for a test / development environment. I am very new to Kafka and docker so some of my terminology may be off

The setup:
custom Windows App - WSL (Debian) with Kafka / zoo-keeper- container - Offset explorer.

I get a green cluster connection in offset explorer but no topics:

[image]
We do see the broker though.

[image]

Docker container cloned from:
https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/README.md

Windows host machine I.P is 192.168.1.143.

From windows cmd I can see WSL has IP 172.25.224.1.

By attaching to a bash shell on the docker container `docker exec -t -i 64a637cea4b9 /bin/bash` I can run `ifconfig` and get the internal ip 172.18.0.2.

From the docker container I can ping the host 192.168.1.143.

From WSL I can ping the container

From the windows host I can pin WSL 172.25.224.1.

From the windows host I can not ping the container 172.18.0.2.
I am not sure if this is relevant but my spider sense is tingling slightly about this failure to ping.

I have modified the docker-compose.yml slightly from the original.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-container
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      DOCKER_API_VERSION: 1.22
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.143
      AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I have also tried editing the two config file within the docker container, /opt/kafka_2.13-2.8.1/config/server.properties and opt/kafka_2.13-2.8.1/config/kraft/server.properties by adding the line:

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

As I read this may help?

I am out of ideas as the connection within offset explorer seems to suggest we have some form of connection but clearly not complete. I don't have a very good understanding of what it going on so it  is probably very simple. Thanks for any possible help!

Comment: I'd suggest not using Docker if you are new to it. You can run Kafka directly in WSL2. In any case, ping doesn't check ports are correct, and doesn't do much for a host to ping itself. Start with `kcat -L -b 192.168.1.143:9092` (install kcat on windows)

Comment: I've not heard of kcat but used nmap to check my port and thy seem to be open. I have installed kafka directly on wsl as suggested by yourself and a colleague but same result of a broker but no topics. I think I may try a test python script to publish a topic.

Comment: Topic information is stored in Zookeeper. If it's saying it's connected to Kafka, but there are no topics then 1) brokers don't have any user topics, by default 2) you should be validating the Zookeeper connection. 3) Why are you letting compose advertise a random port rather than the Kafka default? Kcat will verify the advertised listeners are correct https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seemed to be networking issues between WSL and windows. In the end I installed kafka directly into WLS but still had issue. the solution was four fold.

1. In WLS prefer IV4

   export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True"
   I ended up putting this at the beginning of both bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh and bin/kafka-server-start.sh
2. Prefer IPV4 in windows by adding / setting reg setting

   New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters" -Name "DisabledComponents" -Value 0x20 -PropertyType "Dword"

or if the reg key already exists

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\" -Name "DisabledComponents" -Value 0x20
```

A restart is required for this to take effect.

3. WLS port forwarding
   Using teh script from [here][1] and modifying the ports.
4. Making sure advertised.hosts.name in config/server.properties was set equal to the WSL internal IP returned by ifconfig.

After this I was able to add my topics via a python script or manually using kafkacat.
[1]: https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22